# mailto: with multiple addresses and real names

Tags: email, mailto

I have backend admin tool that manages a number of groups of people working in different sections. From time to time I need to email all the people in one group, so I created a button in my admin tool which does a simple mailto: for all the users in that section. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com, an@example.com, test@testing.com">Mail All</a>
```

And this works fine. However, I wanted to add their real names to the mailto link so when I'm sending the mail I can quickly see who's in the group. So I tried formatting the link like this:

```
<a href="mailto:Foo%20Foo&lt;foo@bar.com&gt,Anne%20Example&lt;an@example.com&gt;,Mr%20Test&lt;test@testing.com&gt;">Mail All</a>
```

But that seemed to only pick up the first email address and list the 'real name' as one long name with commas.

Searching the web, documentation is scant on multiple addresses with real names (only found info when sending one). So wondering whether this is (a) not possible, (b) possible, but I've got the syntax wrong or c) only possible if I use a workaround like copying all the email address data onto the clipboard and paste it into the mail.

Any email gurus out there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I fooled around and got it to work using UTF-8 encoding.

```
"First Last" <firstlastname@example.com>
```

becomes

```
<a href="mailto:%22First%20Last%22%20%3cfirstlastname@example.com%3e">Send Email</a>
```

I was also able to add a bcc field with multiple addresses by following the example above and separated them with commas.

This launched in both Outlook and in Gmail Compose by replacing "mailto:" with "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to="

Answer (score 0):

I say "not possible", at least the way I interpret [RFC 6068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt):

```
The syntax of a 'mailto' URI is described using the ABNF of [STD68], 
non-terminal definitions from [RFC5322] (dot-atom-text, quoted-   
string), and non-terminal definitions from [STD66] (unreserved, pct-  
encoded):

  mailtoURI    = "mailto:" [ to ] [ hfields ]
**to           = addr-spec *("," addr-spec )
  hfields      = "?" hfield *( "&" hfield )
  hfield       = hfname "=" hfvalue
  hfname       = *qchar
  hfvalue      = *qchar
**addr-spec    = local-part "@" domain
**local-part   = dot-atom-text / quoted-string
  domain       = dot-atom-text / "[" *dtext-no-obs "]"
  dtext-no-obs = %d33-90 / ; Printable US-ASCII
                 %d94-126  ; characters not including
                           ; "[", "]", or "\"
  qchar        = unreserved / pct-encoded / some-delims
  some-delims  = "!" / "$" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*"
               / "+" / "," / ";" / ":" / "@"
```

(I've marked the interesting rules with **)

Specifically:

> <addr-spec> is a mail address as specified in [[RFC5322]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), but excluding
> <comment> from [[RFC5322]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).

The address format you are trying to use is called `name-addr` in RFC5322. `addr-spec` is just the name@domain part.